# Gradle assemble specific flavor and build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Running `./gradlew tasks` shows options to assemble all builds for a particular flavor, or all flavors for a particular build. Does there exist an option to assemble for a specific flavor and build combination?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes - you're referring to a specific build variant

```
./gradlew assembleFlavoraBuildb
```

Where your flavor is called `flavora` and your build is `buildb`

Read more here: 
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Building-and-Tasks

Comment: Hmmm been on that page before. I clearly have bad reading comprehension. 

"#1 allows directly building a single variant. For instance assembleFlavor1Debug."